# Get the action attribute of the calling form in AngularJS

Tags: forms, angularjs

I have my form

```php
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit()" action="<?php echo Route::get('auth'); ?>" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
  <!-- the rest -->
</form>
```

And the coffeescript part

```
app.controller 'LoginCtrl', ($scope) ->
  $scope.submit = (where) ->
    # want to the get the form action here
```

Is there any "angular" way to get the form DOM element or the action of the form. I can't hardcode the action in the Javascript file because it changes depending on the current uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't support it, since I'm using jQuery along, I'm just selecting the form by id... too bad AngularJS doesn't pass the element along to the controller, only for directives.